# How to rework rspec json spec without using .items keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Can anyone tell me the updated way to write this rspec spec? It uses the keyword "items" which has been deprecated and I can't figure out how to properly do it. When I include the matchers gem, I get a conflict about which rspec version to use so I'd just like to avoid its use all together.

This is the spec for counting how many courses I see in the index when I create 4:

```
  expect(courses_response[:name]).to have(4).items
```

A sample string I am matching is:

```
{:courses=>[{:courses=>{:id=>1, :name=>"Wilford Rolfson"}}, {:courses=>{:id=>2, :name=>"Mabel Jacobi"}}, {:courses=>{:id=>3, :name=>"Madison Beahan"}}, {:courses=>{:id=>4, :name=>"Miles Corwin"}}]}
```

I have tried:

```
expect(courses_response.length).to eq(4)
```

That yields "1" instead of "4"

These three yield nil:

```
expect(courses_response[:name]).to eq(4)
expect(courses_response[:id]).to eq(4)
expect(courses_response[:row]).to eq(4)
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, because your returned object is a hash with a single key (`:courses`) and value (an array containing the courses), you need to check the length of that array like so:

```
expect(courses_response[:courses].length).to eq(4)
```

This is assuming:

```
courses_response = {:courses=>[{:courses=>{:id=>1, :name=>"Wilford Rolfson"}}, {:courses=>{:id=>2, :name=>"Mabel Jacobi"}}, {:courses=>{:id=>3, :name=>"Madison Beahan"}}, {:courses=>{:id=>4, :name=>"Miles Corwin"}}]}
```